# Identify rotated square in computer generated image

Tags: algorithm

How would it be possible to identify rotated squares in an image?

I have some ideas how to identify them normally, but I'm confused with the "pixel" representation of rotated square. If it is rotated by the angle of 90 degrees it seems that it would be represented by edges that will follow (starting from left point) x+1,y+1 then x+1,y-1 then x-1,y+1 and x-1,y-1. But what happens if angle is different then 90 degrees? How would it be represented in pixels?

And how to detect such square?

Answer (score 0):

If your square edges are well-defined, you can try [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to determine lines on the image and find whether they form a square. Another option - using [OpenCV library to find shape contours](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/detecting-simple-shapes-in-an-image/).
(OpenCV contains Hough transform too)

**[Edit]**
If edge lines are ideal (without gaps and artifacts), then you can try point-by-point traversal:
Scan an image, find any active (non-background) point. It is corner or point on the edge. Check neighbour pixels, find active one. Check next pixel in the same direction and in two adjacent directions (from 8 possible ways). Continue moving until corner is met. Remember corner position. Check for perpendicular direction for the next edge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there any simpler approach than this? If I understand well, this is used in case of images (photos). But what would you use if you have a simple, computer generated, image (for example, you draw a square in Photoshop and rotate it)?